# Redis get multiple sorted sets?

Tags: redis

I have multiple sorted sets, which I have named by keys like:

```
hello:user_id:2015-01-01
hello:user_id:2015-01-02
hello:user_id:2015-01-03
hello:user_id:2015-01-04
etc.
```

Is it possible to get all of these sets for dates between `hello:user_id:2015-01-01` and `hello:user_id:2015-01-04` ?

Comment: Did you check ZUNIONSTORE?

Answer (score 2):

As @zenbeni pointed out this is possible with [ZUNIONSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/ZUNIONSTORE)

Here is how you can run it.

```
ZUNIONSTORE resultzset 4 hello:user_id:2015-01-01 hello:user_id:2015-01-02 hello:user_id:2015-01-03 hello:user_id:2015-01-04
```

Once that runs the result will be stored in `resultzset` which you can query to get the stored values.

```
ZRANGE resultzset 0 -1
```

Comment: manually writing  dates from 01-01 TO 01-04 looks bad to be implemented